# custom authorization and page protection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

need to solve a custom authorization issue.
I already have four tables in my database named:
1. Usermaster
2.Roles
3.RoleMenu
4.Menu

I have implemented this and its working perfectly.
My only issue now is that an authenticated user  can view an unauthorized page by simply entering the page url in the browser.

Any useful ideas apart from forms authentication and folder level access?

Comment: What is your issue with Forms Authentication?  It's well tested, and solid, and used by many many sites, including this one.

Comment: my main issue with forms authentication is performance and customization. Any ideas on how it can be applied in this context?

Comment: What about forms authentication do you find to perform poorly and uncustomizable?

Comment: my main bottleneck is customizing and adapting it to my app?

Comment: HOW is it a bottleneck?  What are you finding difficult?  What specific problems?  general handwaving does not help.

Comment: i have not used form authentication before,i guess i need to create an entire membership database for it. Is there anyway i can adapt it to my already existing database and some tables to implement it?
Give some pointers.

Comment: you are confusing Membership with authentication.  They are not the same thing.  Forms Authentication is merely the means by which you are autheenticated to the site, which is by an encrypted cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project similar to this and i can't seem to find the code anywhere as it was quite awhile ago. I remember the premise though. What i did was i set up a key in the webconfig that had usernames allowed access in a pipedelimited string. Behind the code i would pull in that key as well as the user trying to access the page. I would then search the string and try and match the user. If a match was found the page would load, if a match wasn't found it would redirect them to a page telling them they didn't have access and who to contact to request access. I'll look for the code and edit if i find it.

EDIT

WebConfig

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Users" value="user1|user2|user3|..." />
</appSettings>
```

This piece goes above the

For the .aspx.vb page

```
Dim DomainUserName() As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").Split("\")
    Dim UserName As String = DomainUserName(1)

    Dim Users() As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Users").ToString.Split("|")

    Dim isAllowedAccess As Boolean = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To Users.Count - 1
        If UserName = Users(i) Then
            isAllowedAccess = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If isAllowedAccess = False Then
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    End If
```

Essentially our logins are domain\username so what i'm doing is extracting just the name using a split. I'm then populating the accepted users into an array splitting on the pipe and looping through them searching for a match. when the match is found it allows them access, if a match isn't found they are redirected back to the home page.

Comment: checking up forms authentication now as a viable alternative.